# How can I make it so the width of a DIV changes when my browser width changes?

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
#rootView, #topView {
    width: 100rem;
}
```

How can I make it so the width is 100rem if the browser width is greater than 1000px and 80rem if the browser width is between 800px and 1000px?

Comment: what if its less than 800px?

Comment: see [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up a media query.

```
@media (min-size: 800px) and (max-size: 1000px) {
   #rootView, #topView {
     width: 80rem;
   }
}
@media (min-size: 1001px) {
   #rootView, #topView {
     width: 100rem;
   }
}
```

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

@media screen — The browser identifies itself as being in the “screen” category. This roughly means the browser considers itself desktop-class — as opposed to e.g. an older mobile phone browser (note that the iPhone, and other smartphone browsers, do identify themselves as being in the screen category), or a screenreader — and that it’s displaying the page on-screen, rather than printing it.

```
body{
    background:pink;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  body{
      background:red;
  }
  #rootView, #topView {
    width: 80rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  body{
      background:green;
  }
  #rootView, #topView {
    width: 100rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with javascript.

```
function boo() {
            var width = document.getElementById("body").style.width;
            if (width == "800px")
                document.getElementById("topView").style.width="80rem";
            else
                document.getElementById("topView").style.width="100rem";
}
```

Or something very similar to that. You can get width length, and if larger than whatever. But the other answers may be better.